# ggplot2 add sum to chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Using `mtcars` as an example, I've produced some violin plots. I wanted to add two things to this chart:

1. for each group, list `n`
2. for each group, sum a third variable (e.g. `wt`)

I can do (1) with the geom_text code below although (`n`) is actually plotted on the x axis rather than off to the side.

But I can't work out how to do (2).

Any help much appreciated!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggthemes)

result <- mtcars

ggplot(result, aes(x = gear, y = drat, , group=gear)) +
  theme_tufte(base_size = 15) + theme(line=element_blank()) +
  geom_violin(fill = "white") +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "black", alpha = 0.3, width = 0.1) +
  ylab("drat") + 
  xlab("gear") +
  coord_flip()+
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count.., y = ..count..))
```

Comment: when you say you want to count the third variable, do you mean that you want to find the total weight for each group or do you want the number of unique weights? It seems to me that just counting the third variable would give you the same result as the general count

Comment: Sorry, my miscommunication! I want to *sum* a third variable which is then listed alongside the count for each group

Answer (score 1):

You can add both of these annotations by creating them in your dataframe temporarily prior to graphing. Using the `dplyr` package, you can create two new columns, one with the count for each group, and one with the sum of `wt` for each group. This can then be piped directly into your ggplot using `%>%` (alternatively, you could save the new dataset and insert it into ggplot the way you have it). Then with some minor edits to your `geom_text` call and adding a second one, we can create the plot you want. The code looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggthemes)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

result <- mtcars

result %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  mutate(count = n(), sum_wt = sum(wt)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = gear, y = drat, , group=gear)) +
    theme_tufte(base_size = 15) + theme(line=element_blank()) +
    geom_violin(fill = "white") +
    geom_boxplot(fill = "black", alpha = 0.3, width = 0.1) +
    ylab("drat") + 
    xlab("gear") +
    coord_flip()+
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0("n = ", count), 
                  x = (gear + 0.25), 
                  y = 4.75)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0("sum wt = ", sum_wt), 
                  x = (gear - 0.25),
                  y = 4.75))
```

The new graph looks like this:

[image]

Alternatively, if you create a summary data frame named `result_sum`, then you can manually add that into the `geom_text` calls.

```
result <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(gear = factor(as.character(gear)))

result_sum <- result %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), sum_wt = sum(wt))


ggplot(result, aes(x = gear, y = drat, , group=gear)) +
  theme_tufte(base_size = 15) + 
  theme(line=element_blank()) +
  geom_violin(fill = "white") +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "black", alpha = 0.3, width = 0.1) +
  ylab("drat") + 
  xlab("gear") +
  coord_flip()+
  geom_text(data = result_sum, aes(label = paste0("n = ", count), 
                                   x = (as.numeric(gear) + 0.25), 
                                   y = 4.75)) +
  geom_text(data = result_sum, aes(label = paste0("sum wt = ", sum_wt), 
                                   x = (as.numeric(gear) - 0.25),
                                   y = 4.75))
```

This gives you this:

[image]

The benefit to this second method is that the text isn't bold like in the first graph. The bold effect occurs in the first graph due to the text being printed over itself for all observations in the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks so much for two alternatives - I liked the second one and this worked really well. The positioning is nice and simple and quite flexible. Working

Comment: Thanks so much for two alternatives - I liked the second one and this worked really well. The positioning is nice and simple and quite flexible. However working with a second dataset I hit a problem using categorical data which I have grouped upon... the positioning doesnt work in this instance as there is no continuous scale to locate the geom_text. In the solution you gave, adding result$gear <- as.character(results$gear) before result_sum will reproduce the problem. Any ideas??

Comment: Try converting them to factors using `results %>% mutate(gear = factor(as.character(gear))`. Additionally, you can set the levels of the factors if they are not in the order you want by default by setting the `levels` argument in the `factor` functiom

Comment: My poor R skills showing through here!! I altered the code as below, but get the problem with plotting the position of the geom_text for the y-axis (factors). I use results$gear <- as.factor(as.character(results$gear)) but then get the error:
1: In Ops.factor(gear, 0.25) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(gear, 0.25) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors which obviously means it can#t plot the position on the y-axis as they are factors.

Comment: try this, `results<-result %>% mutate(gear = factor(as.character(gear)))` thereafter, you can use the `results` in the ggplot like `ggplot(results,aes(x = gear, y = drat, group=gear))`

Comment: I updated the second option to show how you can do this with a character variable. What you need to do is first convert it to a factor prior to calculating the summary data set (or also convert the character to factors in the summary data set) and then set `x = as.numeric(gear)` in the `geom_text` call. This will allow you to add the 0.25 or whatever value you want to add to it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who helped.... I used this in the end which plots the calculated values, one set of classes being text based so using vjust to position the vertical offset.

thanks again!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggthemes)

results <- mtcars
results$gear <- as.factor(as.character(results$gear)) #Turn 'gear' to text to simulate classes, then factorise

result_sum <- results %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), sum_wt = sum(wt))

ggplot(results, aes(x = gear, y = drat, group=gear)) +
  theme_tufte(base_size = 15) + theme(line=element_blank()) +
  geom_violin(fill = "white") +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "black", alpha = 0.3, width = 0.1) +
  ylab("drat") + 
  xlab("gear") +
  coord_flip()+
  geom_text(data = result_sum, aes(label = paste0("n = ", count), x = (gear), vjust= 0, y = 5.25)) +
  geom_text(data = result_sum, aes(label = paste0("sum wt = ", round(sum_wt,0)), x = (gear), vjust= -2, y = 5.25))
```